# Is there a way to set iTunes to play in mono?

Tags: itunes, audio, mono, stereo

I've got a set of speakers, but one of them doesn't work.  Is there any way to get iTunes to output to mono, but with both channels?

I'm on Leopard, and going to *System Preferences » Sound » Output* and sliding the Balance all the way to one side doesn't help, as it doesn't combine the channels.

Comment: If your'e running Windows, you may want to checkout [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/117494/force-windows-to-output-only-mono-sound). A "mixer adapter" might do the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A 1/8" mono adapter from Radio Shack might work for you.  Of course, while you're there you could just pick up a new set of speakers;)

I'd also bet that [Audio Hijack Pro](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/audiohijackpro/) can do it for you, but a license for that will cost you just a bit less than a basic new set of computer speakers.

Comment: For what it's worth, it turns out Audio Hijack Pro does do this.  And you can buy a license immediately 24/7.

Answer (score 41):

- Go to the apple symbol (),
- Go to preferences,
- In System go to Accessibility
- Go to the Audio option
- Select "Play as Mono"

That's it, nothing to do in itunes

Comment: This definitely should be the chosen answer :D easy to setup!

Comment: This is a great help, agree it should be chosen. Helped me without going to the store!

Comment: Up voted yours, better than my answer:)

Answer (score 0):

You can open *Audio MIDI Setup.app* from *Utilities* and change your speaker options under *Configure Speakers…* like this:

[image]

They will then only play the left channel (if "1" is chosen), or the right one (if "2" is chosen).

Confirm this by clicking the "left front" or "right front" button – it'll play mono.

Comment: This won't convert stereo to mono, it will just play one of the two stereo channels through both speakers. This can ruin music with significant differences between the left and right channels.

Answer (score -2):

No I don't think so, I think you have to re-record to mono or.. strip the cable of your not working speaker an combine them with the cable of your working speaker, there is a pretty good chance that you will receive stereo output on a speaker.