# Sounds come from only one speaker

Tags: dvd, audio, speakers

I have a DVD which contains a movie, while I'm hearing to title menu's music everything is OK. But as soon as playing the main movie, the sounds come only from one speaker, I try headphone too, only from left speaker I can hear sounds! I try several players such as GOM Player, PowerDVD too. The result is the same!

Why it is like this? and how to fix it?

Comment: Is this for all DVDs, or just this one. If it is just this one, I am inclined to say it was recorded incorrectly, and this is not fixable

Comment: @soandos Thanks for reply, yes only for this one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try going to control panel then click on sounds and audio devices then under speaker setting click the advanced area and check to make sure that it is set for desktop stereo speakers.

Comment: This is exactly the link that I posted in the comment above...

Answer (score 1):

Since it is only this DVD, it is a problem with the DVD and there is nothing that you can do fix this. It was most probably recorded incorrectly.

Comment: do you know nay software that can fix it? for example copying left channel sounds on right channels too...

Comment: take a look [here](http://superuser.com/q/117494/82812)