# Change computer to mono sound?

Tags: windows-7, audio

I'll spare you the long story, but I'd like to know if there's any way to force my computer to output Mono sound, but only when a specific set of headphones are plugged in (namely, my earbuds), but NOT when I plug in other peripherals such as my 2.1 speaker system, or when just using the built-in speakers of the laptop.

Is there any way to be this specific?

Using Windows 7 on Alienware M17x R2

Comment: If you have [this option](http://superuser.com/a/572188/138343) perhaps it will help.

Answer (score 3):

Yes!  Buy a stereo to mono adapter for the earbuds.  There is no way for the jack to differentiate between devices because they are not bluetooth.

something like this:
http://www.radioshack.com/product/index.jsp?productId=2062469&locale=en_US

Comment: I purchased an adapter, but for some reason it makes the sound come out very quiet and at a lower quality. I suspect this may be because my earbuds also include a microphone, so the differing connection could be screwing something up.