# Windows 8 won't output stereo sound

Tags: windows-8, audio, drivers, sound-card

I have two sets of stereo speakers. Speakers on my desk and a pair of headphones.

The speakers are connected to a port on the back and the headphones are connected to a USB port on the front. (indicating this is a software issue)

Both devices only pick up the right channel. It's like windows is only playing mono sound and I can't figure out why.

Here is my advanced audio tab, if this means anything to you:

[image]

No options there for mono or stereo as indicated in [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/117494/force-windows-to-output-only-mono-sound)

I don't think it's the driver. I didn't have any special drivers installed before, but once the problem started to really bother me I tried installing the latest version of the Realtek Audio Driver and it didn't fix it. I can't find any options to change it in the Realtek Audio Manager either.

[image]

**Update:** if I try to reconfigure the speakers and I select the output type as Stereo and then try to test it, I again get no sound when it's supposed to be playing through the left speaker and sound from both speakers when it's only supposed to be the right one.

Comment: If you unplug the headphones does it play correctly? Have you tested these on a different unit hence a bad speaker plug or it's malfunctioning. Have you tested only the headphones and not the speakers to see if it fixed the problem and isolates the problem with hardware/software.

Comment: As stated in the quesiton I'm almost certain it's a software problem, I'm having the same problem on two entirely different devices, both of which were normally operational until recently and the problem persists regardless of which port I plug them into. I have no other computers to test them on.

Comment: Speakers, I have Stereo Headphones and 2.1 desktop speakers. (he deleted the comment this comment was an answer to)

Comment: can you update your question and show which motherboard you are using and if this recently happened or its always happened

Comment: is [this section](http://puu.sh/70xPM.png). does it look like [this](http://puu.sh/70xRq.jpg)? I got there by doing this: Playback > Select Source > Properties > Levels Tab > Balance>

Comment: I'm using the Asus 990FX Sabertooth and no, it wasn't always like this. But I don't know exactly when it changed, it's been going on for a while. And yeah, the balance is set to 100 for both right and left, but changing the left one doesn't do anything. As I said, changing the right one affects both sides.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13101/discussion-between-sickest-and-mark-kramer)