# Force Windows 10 into mono and disable a speaker

Tags: windows-10, audio, speakers, mono, ease-of-access

My cruddy MSI notebook blew its right speaker after 3 months (it makes a horrible distorted noise on anything above the minimum setting).

The only way I can work is put the right speaker to zero on the balance setting in "Speaker properties". But that means any speech on right is often muted. Also annoyingly the balance automatically resets to parity frequently.

The third answer to [Force Windows to output only mono sound](https://superuser.com/questions/117494/force-windows-to-output-only-mono-sound) looked like a partial solution but my Ease of Access, "Other" screen lacks the audio option (see below).

Any idea where this option might have gone?

And, more importantly, any "permanent" solution come to mind? I have checked online and up and down Control Panel and Win 10 settings and can find nothing.

As I often use my PC to run Blu-rays on my TV the ideal solution would be mono only for the internal speaker but overall mono would still be an excellent solution.

Their screen:
[image]

My screen:
[image]

Any thoughts gratefully received.

Comment: Doesn't your sound card have an audio driver ? You should be able to do that from the driver's control panel.

Comment: I know it's a bit late and this might be a stupid question... but are you sure you don't have a scroll bar on the right side of that window? Your screenshot seems cropped so I can't be certain, but I don't see the usual "Have a question" or "Make Windows better." menu entries that should be just under the option for mono audio. Also, is your Windows up to date? I think they only added that option later on.

Comment: Sorry guys should have said as machine developed other problems it went in for a repair. Audio fine ... for now ...

Answer (score 0):

If your soundcard doesn't offer this as a setting (The one buildin on my computer doesn't either), you can use the opensource software [Equalizer APO instead](https://sourceforge.net/projects/equalizerapo/).

It is a versatile audio suite for realtime audio editing with no overhead or delay. It can EQ the sound, but also change channel assignments etc. It has an option to select only one of the two speakers too.

Comment: Thanks but did not want to add yet more software to my overburdened machine.

Comment: If your driver can't do it, then software IS required. But its really good software. ;)